# MySQL database refuses to start on XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I am totally new to how XAMPP works, and I want to start learning php. However, after downloading XAMPP, I encountered somme issues : MySQL Database refuses to start, and I can't figure out what goes wrong. On server events, only the message "Starting MySQL Database..." appears.

I tried to close a presumed already opened My SQL server thanks to the console :
• sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop   leading to the following message : ERROR! MySQL server process #4267 is not running! (yes I work with MacOS)

So I suppose that the issue is not about another instance of MySQL server running in background. Does anyone have a guess on how I could start MySQL database on XAMPP ?

If it can help, I know that i donwloaded MySQL workbench some time ago. I don't know if it could explain a possible conflict between workbench and XAMPP...

Comment: mysql generates an error log, where the error is cleary stated, find it and you can solve your problem

Comment: The error didn't appear on the XAMPP interface, but I figured out how to correctly start it. I have unsuccesfully tried to close a presumed running server with the console, but it worked when I wen into my Mac's preferences -> MySQL -> stop the already running server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered the issue by manually modifying the parameters. I went into my Mac's preferences -> MySQL -> stop the already running server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).